# Newlife.RocketMQ message loss and duplicate

Tags: c#, rocketmq

I am trying to do some test with RocketMQ, and I use C# with Newlife.RocketMQ. I started RocketMQ on my pc and I see the command window open and printing messages -- so that is ok.

So I wrote a simple C# program to test this:

This is the WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
<DockPanel >
    <TextBox x:Name="txtProduce" Text="message 1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30" FontSize="16"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnProduce" Content="Produce" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnProduce_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgProduce" Height="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <Label Content="Consumer" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgConsume" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And now the C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Producer _producer;
    Consumer _consumer;
    ObservableCollection<SendResult> _results = new ObservableCollection<SendResult>();
    object _resultsLock = new object();
    ObservableCollection<MessageExt> _messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageExt>();
    object _messagesLock = new object();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgProduce.ItemsSource = _results;
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_results, _resultsLock);
        dgConsume.ItemsSource = _messages;
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_messages, _messagesLock);
        _producer = new Producer
        {
            Topic = "TopicTest",
            NameServerAddress = "localhost:9876",
            RetryTimesWhenSendFailed = 10
        };
        _producer.Start();
        _consumer = new Consumer
        {
            Topic = "TopicTest",
            NameServerAddress = "localhost:9876"
        };
        _consumer.OnConsume = (q, ms) =>
        {
            foreach(var item in ms.ToList())
                _messages.Add(item);
            return true;
        };
        _consumer.Start();
    }
    private int _i = 1;
    private void BtnProduce_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var content = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + ":" + txtProduce.Text;
            var message = new Message()
            {
                Body = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content),
                Keys = (_i++).ToString(),
                Tags = _i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd",
                Flag = 0,
                WaitStoreMsgOK = true
            };
            var sr = _producer.Publish(message);
            _results.Add(sr);
            txtProduce.Text = "message " + _i;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

And now I see problems:

1. "message 3" appear twice in the consumer message list.
2. when I start 2 instances of my application, when a message is sent, it is consumed by either application instance 1 or instance 2, and not both.

Why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

question 1：after return true when consumed, the message will never comes to you again unless commit fail.

question 2: rocketmq has two ways of consuming： cluster and broadcast.

i.e: 2 consumer instances, 100 messages sent,

for cluster: 50 for consumer instance 1, another 50 for consumer instance 2

for broadcast: 100 for consumer instance 1, same 100 for consumer instance 2

consume doc : https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/4.x/consumer/02push/#cluster-and-broadcast-mode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).